# Not able to send mail using mailx

Tags: shell, mailx

I am not able to receive emails sent via the below mailx code of lines from Shell script.This mailx is part of the script. When I try to execute the mailx block separately in a script, it works.

```
        subject="Failure: $number|$server|$environment|$jname"
        body="$script_output"
        dos2unix $body  2>/dev/null
        if [ ! -z "$body" ]
        then
           mailx -a "$file" -r "$from_mail" -s "$mail_subject" -b "$to_mail"  2>/dev/null <<EOF
    Hi,

    Testing email.
    $script_output

    EOF
```

Can anyone help here? I tried changing the Mail subject by removing pipe '|' symbol and it worked. Not sure how. Please advise.

Comment: You should check the logs, the `mailq` (mail-queue), and ev. the configuration of your server. And `2>/dev/null` is not helping to find the cause.

Comment: You have a variable named `subject`, but you use `mail_subject`.  Is this an accurate representation of the problematic code?

Comment: @clueless : Run your script with `set -x` enabled, and check the exit code of `mailx`. And, of course, don't throw away the stderr - at least not while you are still debugging.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The subject and mail_subject was a typo

Comment: @user1934428 I was able to write the output of the mailx to a file and then identified that there was an invalid character at the end of $file1's value Had removed that and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the file being attached. the file name had an invalid character at the end and hence it was causing issue in sending the email. When the output of mailx was put into separate file, we were able to identify the ^M character. After removing this, I was able to send email. Thanks!